# Reducing the height of the collapse bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

Is there any way to reduce the height of the navigation bar in this?
http://www.bootply.com/render/1dopQbJEMd. I am using exactly the same css properties in the link.I tried with the height property in css. But its not getting reduced.

Comment: share your code. relevant HTML and CSS for the menu and we will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after inspecting that code, i saw that

1. `.navbar` has `min-height:50px` , change it to `min-height:0` so it will inherit the `height` from it's contents
2. `.navbar-brand` has `padding:15px 15px`, reduce the `top` and `bottom` padding how you want, for example `padding:5px 15px`
3. `.navbar-nav>li>a` has `padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px` reduce them as well to `5px` as you did on point 2
4. `.navbar-text` has `margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px` , reduce it also to `5px` as you did on point 2 and 3

in the end you will have CSS :

```
.navbar {
   min-height:0;
}
 .navbar-brand {
   padding:5px 15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
   padding-top:5px;
   padding-bottom:5px;
}
.navbar-text {
   margin-top:5px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

the height of your `.navbar` will be `30px`, with `20px` less than before

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

There you can see the variables you can change. One of them is the height of the navbar. Change that variable and download the CSS and JS files at the bottom of the page. Use the new files instead of default Bootstrap files.

You can also try changing the CSS, but I find it way harder.